# How to avoid double backslash in MySQL's SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, backslash

In MySQL, the following:

```
SELECT '\\' INTO OUTFILE 'c:/temp/backslash.dump';
```

writes two backslashes to the file, which makes sense.

Trying to dump a single backslash, I changed SQL_MODE, like that:

```
SET SESSION SQL_MODE='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
SELECT '\' INTO OUTFILE 'c:/temp/backslash.dump';
```

but got two backslashes again.

Is there a way to dump a single backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
SELECT '\\' INTO OUTFILE 'c:/temp/backslash.dump' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '|';
```